# How to use AWS Amplify or non python SDK's to make API calls to AWS Personalize?

Tags: amazon-web-services, personalization

I was following the AWS personalize docs, when I reached the section on making api calls to get recommendations from the campaign (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_RS_GetRecommendations.html), the docs have examples for making these calls with their python sdk and CLI, but not for Amplify even though it is listed as an option. Has anyone started using Personalize without a CLI or Python SDK, how did you do it?

I emailed AWS support and all they had at the moment was the setup link in the docs that I already linked. I also tried googling the method names on the Amplify, and JS sdk docs just in case it was there.

this is what they said to use

```
POST /recommendations HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "campaignArn": "string",
   "itemId": "string",
   "numResults": number,
   "userId": "string"
}
```

I tried making a simple curl on the campaign url with /recomendations, but that didn't work, I assume the call must be made from something that has your public and secret amazon key stored.